# Mongame Content Pipeline: Compile FBX with embedded texture to XNB

Tags: xna, monogame, fbx, assimp, content-pipeline

I have a `FBX` with `embedded texture` in it. And I can view the `FBX` displaying its texture in `Autodesk FBX Review` in another computer.

When I try to use `Monogame Content Pipeline` tool (`MGCP.exe`) to compile it to `XNB` it got error like:

> path to texture not existed

So the question is does `MGCP` tool support to compile `FBX` with embedded texture into `XNB`? And does it produce **a single XNB file** for this? 
(Note that it works fine with FBX having external texture but it produces additional XNB file for the associated texture which is I don't want)

Do I need to write the custom FbxImporter to do this?

Comment: You need to write your own ModelProcessor for pipeline import.  [Here's one I wrote previously](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2009/08/22/on-the-fly-effect-material-and-model-mapping/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that MonoGame is currently using an older version of the model importer library, that does not support reading embedded textures. So I'm afraid you'd have to write a custom `FbxImporter` or modify the MonoGame one with the latest Assimp version.

If I remember correctly, XNA produced separate files even for embedded textures. The model format was not designed to carry additional texture data. If you really need to have them in a single file, you'll have to also create a new content processor.

Comment: I submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/4967) to MonoGame.